# Notification drop down not counting all votes

Tags: bug, notifications, user-interface

It seems that it's missing a couple, this matched the app output as well. Though the main reputation gain tab is getting them all.

[image]

Comment: This also happened to me when I was near the 200 rep cap, idk if it’s correlated or just more noticeable when I’m picking up lots of rep because higher sample size

Comment: That's funny; I don't think I've seen that one before.

Comment: @Dubukay, it happened fairly early on, I was wondering if it would catch up, but it seems not.